# How to know which image is being viewed in UIScrollView? Also, is it possible to loop scrolling for an endless effect?

Tags: iphone, indexing, uiscrollview

This is what I'm trying to do, and I'm not sure if it's possible using UIScrollView. First, I don't care about zooming, all I care is that the user is able to scroll through images just like the Photo App, this I got. But how do I know which image he is viewing while using UIScrollView? For instance, if he stops on the 3rd image out of 10 images in the view, how do I know he's on that image? I can't find a way to access the index (is this accessible)??

Also, bonus question, once the user scrolls to the last image, I don't want the scrolling to stop but I want it to loop so that image 1 comes after image 10. And vice versa, if you scroll left passed image 1, you'll see image 10. I'm not asking for the logic, I can do this in an array very simply, I just don't know how to access (if it's even possible) the indexing of the images in the scroll view.

If it's not, does anyone have a solution to do this?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this will help you.

// scrollview is the view in which you are loading the images.

CGFloat pageWidth = scrollView.frame.size.width;

int page = floor((scrollView.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1;

Thanks,

jim.